# How to store value of variable a

Tags: c

```
int countRec(struct TreeNode* root)
{
    int a = 0;
    int c = countRec(root->left);
    c += countRec(root->right);
    if(root->data % 2 == 0)
        c += 1;
    if (c % 2 != 0)
        a++;
    return a;
}
int CountSubTrees(struct TreeNode *root)
{
  if(root==NULL)
    return -1;
return countRec(root);    
}
```

I want to find subtrees with odd count of even value nodes. But a sets to 0 after each round. How to sum all value of a. For ex, for  input: 1 2 3. Answer should be 2 as (1 + 0 + 1). But, it return 1 which is the final value of a. I tried static int a = 0. but it doesn't work. Returning c will return count of even nodes not subtrees with odd count of even value nodes.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this function?  What are you trying to accomplish?  Also, it is supposed to be calling itself recursively?

Comment: Please show more context. How do you call your function? There are no iterations visible in your snippet as there is no loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You want to accumulate the results of several calls to `your_function()`? Doing so using a variable inside the scope of `your_function` could be done with `static int a = 0;` and then each call to `your_function` would have the accumulated value from all the calls, but there's a 99.9% chance this is not what you really should do depending upon your context. As Djamel indicate in his answer, you would normally use a variable local to the caller to do the accumulation, and do `accum_a += your_function();`...

Comment: It looks like what you're really summing is `c`.  So just return `c` instead of `a`.  You also need a base case to stop the recursion, i.e. `if (!root) return 0;`

Answer (score 1):

So you would like to store the last value: `a`

You have to make a function with your snipped code like so

```
int calculate_a()
{ 
 int a = 0;
 int c = countRec(root->left);
  c += countRec(root->right);
 if(root->data % 2 == 0)
  c += 1;
 if (c % 2 != 0)
  a++;
 return a; 
}
```

And then in your main or something like that you do

```
int main()
{
  int my_var = calculate_a();
}
```

And your variable a will be store in `my_var`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i want to sum all the values of a and return the sum. value of a again set to 0 after each iteration. how i should solved it?

Comment: @GeekyCode Then maybe you should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Then use `my_var += calculate_a();` and don't forget to inialize `my_var= 0;`